# CSS sibling selector not triggering

Tags: css, html

I have the following in my CSS (in de-bug mode with checkbox displayed but will be hidden in final):

```
<style type="text/css">
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: sans-serif; }
#nav-trigger { display: none; }
#nav-icon { display: none; }
#navigation { display: block; }
nav     { width: 100%; text-align: center; }
nav ul  { float: right; line-height: 50px; }
nav li  { display: inline; list-style-type: none; }
nav a   { text-decoration: none; padding: 10px; color: #999; }
nav a:hover { color: #C00; }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
nav ul  { display: block; float: none; margin-top: 50px; background-color: #C00; }
nav li  { display: block; }
nav a   { display: block; padding: 3px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC; }
nav a:hover { color: #FFF;}

#nav-trigger { display: block; }
#navigation { display: none; }
#nav-icon { font-size:32px;display:block;position:relative;width:40px;height:40px;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;-moz-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none;margin-left:auto;margin-right:8px; }
#nav-icon::before { content:"";position:absolute;top:.25em;left:4px;width:1em;height:.125em;color:#fff;border-top:.375em double #ddd;border-bottom:.125em solid #ddd;box-sizing:content-box }
#nav-trigger:checked ~ #navigation { display: block; }
}
</style>
```

My HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
<label for="nav-trigger" id="nav-icon"></label>
<nav id="navigation">    
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My navigation is responsive when resizing the window, and hides the nav menu when less then 480px, and my hamburger icon displays, but when I click the icon (or corresponding checkbox) my menu doesn't appear. I have some relationship issue with my CSS sibling selector (last line of my CSS).

Trying to stay away from JavaScript/JQuery.

Need some help!

Thanks!

Comment: where's input box in your html?

Comment: It seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/9c7afqhg/ - when you check the checkbox the navigation links are shown - could you explain what the problem is?

Comment: may be testing in old browser?

Answer (score 0):

You should be use jQuery for "check action":

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#nav-trigger').change(function() {
       if($(this).is(":checked")){
          $('#navigation').show();
       } else { 
          $('#navigation').hide();
       }
    });
});
```

Read more:
http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: this can be done using css only. and OP's css is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It was coder error (lack of sleep). Retested code in different browser (thank you Bhojendra and Danield).